# How does online backup work in case of hardware failure?

Tags: backup, windows-backup

I am talking about any service out there (BackBlaze, Carbonite, etc...).  Consider the following scenario that actually happened last week.

Power went out and my NTFS drive (connected to a NAS of sorts, RT-N56 Asus Router) got corrupted. And by corrupted I mean it lost the last month worth of changes.  Other than that the hard continued working fine as if nothing happened.  And of course, I didn't know it at the time because it just sits behind the NAS and I didn't think to check.

My question is this.  If the last month of hard drive changes simply disappeared, the online backup software would have simply backed up what it sees.  Would I be able to go back in time (with the online backup provider) prior to the power loss and retrieve the lost data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I use CrashPlan.com and they do provide this facility. [Here is a quote](http://www.crashplan.com/consumer/details.html)

> **Flexible Restore Options** With CrashPlan backup software, you can go
>   back in time and choose to restore specific versions of files based on
>   date. You can also tell CrashPlan where to save the files when you
>   restore and whether or not to rename them.

I'm sure other online backup services should be providing the same option. [I went for Crashplan just because it stores my deleted files indefinitely, so it can double-up to free my laptop's harddisk space.]